# What's the difference between ?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless and ?anroid:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless

Tags: android

On 4.x devices, layout files using `?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` result in crashes but `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` doesn't. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` is the appcompat support library implementation which works backward upto API 7 while `?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` is the internal implementation, which is not present in older API levels. hence crashes.

Comment: it's introduced in API level 21 (Lollipop). also, i think it's `?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`

Comment: yes, you're right, I guess the OP posted wrong name for it.

Comment: What about `?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` ?